# SQL query to remove some items based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I have below values in select query,

```
"IND"
"UK"
"FR"
```

Case 1: If I have "IND", "UK" and "FR", it needs return only

```
"IND"
"EU"
```

Case 2: If I have "IND" and "UK", it needs return as

```
"IND"
```

Case 3: If I have "IND" and "FR", it needs return as

```
"IND"
```

Note: If I have both "UK" and "FR" only, I have to consider the value.

Comment: I really don't understand what your goal is here. I feel like we're missing some data. Is your table really only 1 column wide?

Comment: yes. table has only one column for this requirement

Comment: Where does "EU" come from? It's not in your data.

Comment: EU is not our list

Answer (score 2):

This **appears** to get the answer you're after, but I doubt it's the "best" (and it'll scale awfully):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.CC,
           COUNT(CASE V.CC WHEN 'Ind' THEN 1 END) OVER () AS Ind,
           COUNT(CASE V.CC WHEN 'UK' THEN 1 END) OVER () AS UK,
           COUNT(CASE V.CC WHEN 'FR' THEN 1 END) OVER () AS FR
    FROM (VALUES ('IND'),
                 ('UK'),
                 ('FR')
                 ) V(CC))
SELECT CASE WHEN UK > 0 AND FR > 0 AND C.CC = 'UK' THEN 'EU' ELSE C.CC END AS CC
FROM CTE C
WHERE (Ind > 0 AND UK > 0 AND FR > 0 AND C.CC IN ('UK','IND'))
   OR (Ind = 0 AND UK > 0 AND FR > 0 AND C.CC = 'UK')
   OR (Ind > 0 AND (UK = 0 OR FR = 0));
```

In truth, you might be better off pivoting your data; but with so little to work with I'd have to make assumptions (not something I'm going to do).